# Share model from global area to different package in Guvnor

Tags: drools, rule-engine

In Guvnor global area I have uploaded different jar which contains model classes.

After that, I create some packages and create DRL rule inside. Is it possible for these package's rules reference to the model in global area?

Currently my workaround is: create all these rules in global area, then import these rules to different packages, so they can reference to model classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the model to the packages where you need it.

Here is how you do it:

1. Make the model into the global area
2. Start making a new model
3. In the New Model popup select the "Import Asset From Global" area selection
4. Select your model (or any asset) and the package you want to import into

Comment: I am using this approach but it is too annoying as I create ten packages which require me to import the model ten times.